# How should I call Cntk.Core-2.5.dll from C#?

Tags: cntk, win64, interopservices

I have trouble calling Cntk functions from C#. The header file I'm using is CNTKLibraryC.h from a binary CNTK installation, and the DLL that I load is Cntk.Core-2.5.dll from the same installation. My interop signature for CNTK_LoadModel at the moment:

`[DllImport(DllName, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
                    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 private static extern IntPtr CNTK_LoadModel(
            IntPtr modelFilePath,
            IntPtr device,
            out IntPtr model);`

This "works" if I use the model file name (run through `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni()`) for both `modelFilePath` and `device`, but I can't call `CNTK_ReleaseModel` afterwards for then the program crashes. Sometimes I also succeed if I pass a non-existing path to `modelFilePath`, so it's obvious that the *second* argument is taken as the model file name, contrary to what the function signature suggests. I suspect there's something I've overlooked here. I am not used to calling native 64 bit DLLs from C#, only 32 bit. What, for instance, is the correct calling convention?

Comment: There is a CNTK [C# library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/using-cntk-with-csharp). Does that not do what you need instead of calling C++?

Comment: It isn't .net Core compatible yet, as opposed to the native .dll/.so approach, and I need to run some things cross-platform ASAP.